# Keep common tables in one unique database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a db (SQL Server 2008R2) and some common tables have to be moved out into another db because are going to be dictionary data for many clients. For compatibility reason is easy to have them in one place.

I can use synonyms, I tried and works!. My problem is about foreign keys, SQL Server does not support cross database foreign keys.

I can use triggers but is risky... is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Could you keep your "master" of your common tables in a separate database, and then replicate those tables into the various databases that use them, into a `common` schema? That way, you'd have **(a)** one master to keep track of your common tables, and **(b)** a copy of those common tables in each database so you could use normal referential integrity

Comment: I can do that, but I have to maintain those tables in all clients, that is something I would like to avoid. I believe there are not too many options for that. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @rgx71: If you use Microsoft's replication tools, you would not "maintain" all the tables independently -- they could be maintained in one primary location and would be copied out with replication.  Provide more details about the data contained in the tables and we may be able to help more.

Comment: Who is changing/adding data in your dictionary table to the extent that you need explicit foreign keys? If someone screws up the data in your user tables, what's the worst that happens? An inner join leaves those rows out? Sometimes you need to sacrifice 100% protection in the name of other benefits. Oh, and triggers are only risky if they're written sloppily. :-)